# Laravel primary key incrementation in eloquent and migration

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration, primary-key, auto-increment

So I have custom primary keys and I am not sure If I need to define the incrementation in both eloquent and migrations?

### Eloquent

```
class Question extends Model 
{
protected $primaryKey = 'que_id';
protected $keyType = 'tinyInteger'; 
public $autoincrement = true;
}
```

### Migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->tinyInteger('que_id')->autoIncrement();
        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Or it is just enough to define it like this?

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->tinyInteger('que_id')->primary();
        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

- `$keyType` supports `int[eger]` and `string`
- There is no `$autoincrement` property, it's called `$incrementing`.

Migration:

- The second parameter of `tinyInteger()` etc. is `$autoIncrement = false`.
- If you mark a column as `$autoIncrement`, you don't need and can't use `->primary()` (at least on MySQL).

Comment: I need this for a  php script and this approach won't work for me. Because I would need to script different cases for string and every integer. That's why I define them like that   `$table->tinyInteger('que_id')->autoIncrement();` instead of  `$table->tinyIncrements('que_id');`

**My parsing data looks like that (YML file):**

`que_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }`

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question. I updated my answer.